# hung up troubleshooting packet discards

Tags: cisco, packetloss

My network consists of Cisco switches. I am seeing a significant amount (upwards of millions of packets per day) transmit drops between two switches. One being a 3750 and the other a 3560. The peak throughput of this link is only upper 400Mbps, so it shouldn't be a bandwidth issue.

At this point, I am sort of clueless where to look or what tools I can use to determine what packets are dropping and why. I can setup a SPAN port on that link and Wireshark it, but I don't know if that could tell me anything. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you talking about output drops in the `show interface` output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you determining that your peak throughput is 400Mbps?  If it's off the interface counters, especially the 5 minute averages, you could very well be carrying microbursts that are maxing out the interface for very short periods, which don't show up in the counter averages.

Comment: Kyle Brandt wrote a [blog about this and why it matters](http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/06/27/per-second-measurements-dont-cut-it/) last year.